# При нажатии на кнопку должна открыться форма для каждой кнопки

Tags: javascript, form

Есть 2 кнопки и 2 формы. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку появлялась форма, соответствующая этой кнопке. т.е. для кнопки заявка должна выпасть форма для заявки. А для резюме - форма для резюме. Как сделать закрытие, я знаю.

```
<div class="info">
    <button>Заявка</button>
    <button>Резюме</button>
</div>
<div class="form">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="ФИО" required>
            <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" required>
            <input class="button" type="submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="form">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="ФИО" required>
            <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" required>
            <input class="button" type="submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    let forms = document.querySelectorAll('.form');
    
   

buttons.forEach(function(item, index) {
    item[index].addEventListener('click', openWindow);
});
function openWindow() {
    forms[index].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
buttons.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() { openWindow(index); });
});
function openWindow(index) {
  forms[index].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: все получилось, спасибо.